# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.$dismiss()')

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I need to test my signin process using karma unit testing, but I am stuck with an error while executing the test.

My controller code for login:

```
      $scope.signin = function (valid) {
        if (valid) {
            $http.post('/auth/signin', $scope.credentials).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                // If successful we assign the response to the global user model
                $scope.authentication.user = response.user;

                localStorage.setItem('token',response.token.logintoken);
                // And redirect to the index page
                $scope.$dismiss();

            }).error(function (response) {
                $scope.error = response.message;
            });
        } else {
            $scope.userSigninrequredErr = true;
        }
    };
```

Karma test code:

```
(function () {
// Authentication controller Spec
describe('AuthenticationController', function () {
    // Initialize global variables
    var AuthenticationController,
            scope,
            $httpBackend,
            $stateParams,
            $cookieStore,
            notify,
            $location,
            modal;

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toEqualData: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: angular.equals(actual, expected)
                        };
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });

    // Load the main application module
    beforeEach(module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName));

    // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
    // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
    // with the same name as the service.
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$stateParams_, _$httpBackend_, _$cookieStore_, _notify_) {
        // Set a new global scope
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        // Point global variables to injected services
        $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $cookieStore = _$cookieStore_;
        notify = _notify_;
        $location = _$location_;
        modal = jasmine.createSpyObj('modal', ['show', 'hide']);
        // Initialize the Authentication controller
        AuthenticationController = $controller('AuthenticationController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));



    it('$scope.signin() should login with a correct user and password', function () {
        // Test expected GET request  {user: 'Fred', token: {logintoken: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9'}}
        scope.credentials.user = 'jenson';
        scope.credentials.token = {logintoken: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9'};
        $httpBackend.when('POST', '/auth/signin').respond(200, scope.credentials);

        scope.signin(true);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', /\.html$/).respond('');
        $httpBackend.flush();

        // Test scope value
        expect(scope.credentials.user).toEqual('jenson');
        expect($location.url()).toEqual('/dashboard');
    });

}
```

I'm getting the correct response after executing karma test but the following error is showing in the devtools console.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.$dismiss()')

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the `AuthenticationController` code - where is `$scope.$dismiss()` defined? Or is this controller normally run via a modal service?

Comment: $dismiss is already available on modal scope, no mroe functions used in controller

Comment: $dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - A method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that in "real" code, the modal service is invoking the controller and creating a new scope for you, populating the `$dismiss()` method on it, but in your unit test, you are invoking the controller manually (using the `$controller` service), meaning there is no `$scope.$dismiss()` function, hence the error.

Instead, you need to either do what you do in the real code, and use the modal service to instantiate your controller OR at the very least, mimic what the modal service does and add some stub functions on your new scope, including `$dismiss()`.

Comment: Thanks gregl for your valuable answer, here i passed $modalinstance to controller and used $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); for discarding the popup.